# How do I center a TextBlock to a given position

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

A TextBlock should be centered to a position x (or y when Orientation is vertical).
I implemented:

```
TextBlock text = new TextBlock();
// Some code to define text, font, etc. here

// Turn if Orientation is vertical
if (Orientation == Orientation.Vertical) 
{
  text.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform() { Angle = 270 };
}

// Update, then ActualWidth is set correctly
text.UpdateLayout();

// Position of label centered to given position
double halfWidth = text.ActualWidth / 2;
double x1 = (Orientation == Orientation.Horizontal) ? x - halfWidth : x;
double y1 = (Orientation == Orientation.Horizontal) ? y : y + halfWidth;

Canvas.SetLeft(text, x1);
Canvas.SetTop(text, y1);

Children.Add(text); // Add to Canvas
```

This works actual fine, but is it possible to do this without `UpdateLayout`. If I remove `UpdateLayout`, then I do not get the position I am looking for, because ActualWidth is (of course) zero.

Comment: you know that if you use a Grid as Container you will have it immediately centered? Beside that: try with LayoutTransform and not RenderTransform

Comment: What is the parent control?? What is the context of this code?

Comment: @fantasticfix I've to use RenderTransform, because this runs in WPF & Silverlight. SL does not know LayoutTransform.

Comment: Parent of TextBox is a Canvas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be able to do that by binding the `Canvas.Top`/`Canvas.Left` values to the TextBlock's `ActualWidth`/`ActualHeight` and using a `Converter`.

Here's an example. I'm using a custom `MathConverter` that I usually use for mathematical formulas (code can be found [here](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/the-math-converter/)), but you could also use a plain converter that returns half of whatever value it gets passed.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" 
                    Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                    Path=ActualWidth,
                    Converter={StaticResource MathConverter}, 
                    ConverterParameter=@VALUE/2}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" 
                    Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                    Path=ActualHeight,
                    Converter={StaticResource MathConverter}, 
                    ConverterParameter=@VALUE/2}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

**Edit**

Just re-read the question and realized you're trying to center the TextBlock at a specific x,y coordinate on the Canvas. In that case, you'll need to implement a `MultiConverter` instead of a regular `Converter` so that you can pass it two parameters: the X/Y value, and the ActualHeight/ActualWidth value

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you wrote this code in the constructor. It would be a reason why ActualWidth has no value. **All the code hasn't been tested** (no IDE available). You need to do this after the Loaded Event, after WPF has built the layout. This is a routed event, btw.

```
public class Class1{
public Class1 ()
{
    this.Loaded += (sender, args) =>
    {
        TextBlock text = new TextBlock();

        if (Orientation == Orientation.Vertical) 
        {
          text.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform() { Angle = 270 };
        }

        double halfWidth = text.ActualWidth / 2;
        double x1 = (Orientation == Orientation.Horizontal) ? x - halfWidth : x;
        double y1 = (Orientation == Orientation.Horizontal) ? y : y + halfWidth;

        Canvas.SetLeft(text, x1);
        Canvas.SetTop(text, y1);
        Children.Add(text);
    };
}
```

This code will probably work. Of course, the way I read your code, this code seems to be situated in the constructor from a class that you derived from Canvas. There should normally be no need to do so, except when you really need to extend the core functionality of the canvas control. You can make reusable components on top of existing controls by creating a UserControl. You should especially use this approach if you don't need to override any method of the Canvas.

Alternatively, if you just want to have a centered item inside a container, the following xaml will do that just fine:

```
     <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="Haha!" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
     </Grid>
```

Comment: I don't think this will work because I believe you need to render a control before you can get it's `ActualWidth`

Comment: @Rachel: Exactly. That's why we should try to get the actualwidth after the loaded event.

Comment: @Em1: Did not work for the xaml above? Because this works for in XamlPad. Of course, the alignment properties won't take effect if the layout container doesn't use them (e.g. Canvas)

Comment: @Alex Maker I can't use HorizontalAlignment because I do not want to center to a Container.